# How to make uncheck in except selected values in onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i want to do while onclick the button i want to uncheck the fields,and i am using data list , in that datalist suppose i selected Marathahalli means except marathahalli remaining all values i want to make uncheck, i tried but here  all values are unchecking, how to do if anyone knows means please update my snippet

```js
$('.options').on('change', function() {
  var locality = $('#options option[value="' + $('#areaName').val() + '"]').data('id');
    $('#locality_id').val(locality);
}).change();

 $("#search1").click(function(){
        
    var localityId = $("#locality_id").val();

    if(localityId != ''){
        $('.myCheckbox').attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input list="options" type="name" class="form-control options" style="height: 34px; width: 100%;border-radius:0px;" name="areaName" id="areaName" placeholder="Locality" rel="" value="">

<datalist id="options">

<option data-id="1" value="Marathahalli"></option>

<option data-id="2" value="Silk Board"></option>

<option data-id="3" value="Jaya Nagar"></option>

<option data-id="5" value="Kadubeesanahalli"></option>

<option data-id="6" value="Bellandur"></option>

<option data-id="7" value="Kundalahalli"></option>

<option data-id="8" value="JP nagar"></option>
    </datalist>
<input type="hidden" name="localityId" id="locality_id" value="">

<button id="search1" type="button">Click Me!</button>


<form id="filterForm">
   
        <ul style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="1" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Marathahalli</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="2" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Silk Board</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="3" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Jaya Nagar</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="5" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Kadubeesanahalli</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="6" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Bellandur</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="7" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Kundalahalli</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="8" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">JP nagar</label></li>
    </ul>

       
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are explicitly marking all of them as unchecked and not filtering them. Modified you code.

```js
$('.options').on('change', function() {
  var locality = $('#options option[value="' + $('#areaName').val() + '"]').data('id');
    $('#locality_id').val(locality);
}).change();

 $("#search1").click(function(){
        
    var localityId = $("#locality_id").val();

    if(localityId != ''){
        $('.myCheckbox').each(function () {
          if (localityId === $(this).val()) {
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
          } else {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
          }
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input list="options" type="name" class="form-control options" style="height: 34px; width: 100%;border-radius:0px;" name="areaName" id="areaName" placeholder="Locality" rel="" value="">

<datalist id="options">

<option data-id="1" value="Marathahalli"></option>

<option data-id="2" value="Silk Board"></option>

<option data-id="3" value="Jaya Nagar"></option>

<option data-id="5" value="Kadubeesanahalli"></option>

<option data-id="6" value="Bellandur"></option>

<option data-id="7" value="Kundalahalli"></option>

<option data-id="8" value="JP nagar"></option>
    </datalist>
<input type="hidden" name="localityId" id="locality_id" value="">

<button id="search1" type="button">Click Me!</button>


<form id="filterForm">
   
        <ul style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="1" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Marathahalli</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="2" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Silk Board</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="3" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Jaya Nagar</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="5" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Kadubeesanahalli</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="6" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Bellandur</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="7" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">Kundalahalli</label></li>
                    
        <li><label class="space"><input type="checkbox" name="localityId" value="8" checked="" onclick="myFunction()" class="myCheckbox">JP nagar</label></li>
    </ul>

       
  
</form>
```

Comment: your code is not working perfectly , i will tell what is the problem happening suppose in our datalist first time i am selecting Marathahalli means this values checked it ok but next second time i removing Marathahalli and again i am selecting Jaya Nagar means , Marathahalli should unchecked and Jaya Nagar should checked it has to happen like this but you code is not happening based on my requirement.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer for future generations =P